# Can you explain 'but that's beside the point'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean, but that is not what I am trying to point out? That is only a trivia, what I am trying to say is something else.

Comment: If you type in 'beside the point' as a search in this site, you will find lots of usages of it. Look as some of them, and if you have not got a clear idea of the meaning after that, cut one out and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

"Beside the point" is an idiom meaning that what the person just said is irrelevant, out of context, or not important to the topic being discussed.

Example:

A: Those tacos have red shells. Yuck!
B: That's beside the point. I ate the tacos earlier and they taste the same, even though their shells are a weird color.

Comment: I don't think your example really fits.  Usually, the expression is used in an argument when one person brings up something that is irrelevant to the discussion.